# Moving a folder across the network

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I need to move (not copy then delete, for the sake of file verification) a folder from a network folder to another network folder using Powershell.

I have tried `Move-Item` (where `test1` is a folder):

```
PS C:\Users\user\Documents> Move-Item test1 \\SomeServer\c$\some_folder\
Move-Item : Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volumes.
At line:1 char:10
+ Move-Item <<<<  test1 \\SomeServer\c$\some_folder\
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\user\Documents\test1:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Am I missing something simple here? A simple way to do this?

I did try `robocopy`:

```
robocopy /MOVE test1 \\SomeServer\c$\some_folder\
```

Which partially worked, but it lost the `test1` folder (meaning `test` did not show up on `some_folder`) and only the files within that folder ended up on `\\SomeServer\c$\some_folder\`

This is how the results should look:

**Working dir** (before move):

- test1 (folder w/ files in it)
- test2 (folder w/ files in it)
- test3 (folder w/ files in it)
- file.txt

**Working dir** (after move):

- test2 (folder w/ files in it)
- test3 (folder w/ files in it)
- file.txt

**\\SomeServer\c$\some_folder\** (expected after move):

- test1 (folder w/ files in it)

The issue is that when I use robocopy, the result is `files in it` show up in the result but no `test1` folder...

I've tried robocopy with a /s and /move, still no luck.

I found something like:

```
set folder="test1"

robocopy /MOVE "%folder%" "\\SomeServer\c$\some_folder\%folder%"
```

Almost works, but the folder metadata (date modified/created) is lost and that needs to remain.

Comment: (1) Are you using PowerShell 3, and have you verified the local/remote permissions? (2) This [PowerShell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7404879/165358) will do Copy-Item followed by compare-object and Remove-Item if equal.

Comment: 1) Version 2   3) I was hoping to avoid "copy, then delete manually in script" but I'll consider that

Comment: Moving to a different filesystem (local or remote) *is* copy and then delete. There’s no way around that.

Comment: @DanielB Ah gotcha. So when users are doing a Ctrl+X and a Ctrl+V of a folder between drives using Windows Explorer, what commands is it using to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can use Robocopy to move a whole *folder* (`test1`) into another folder (`some_folder`) on a different server, while maintaining date stamps, etc.:

`ROBOCOPY "test1" "\\SomeServer\c$\some_folder\test1" /MOVE /COPY:DAT /DCOPY:T`

From the `ROBOCOPY /?` usage info:

```
/COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
                      (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps).
                      (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

/DCOPY:T :: COPY Directory Timestamps.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use PowerShell 3 - I think some limitations were removed from Move-Item.

The following PowerShell script will do `Copy-Item` followed by `compare-object` and `Remove-Item` only if equal :

```
$source = "<UNC Path>"
$destination = "<UNC Path>"

if (test-path $destination -PathType Container) 
{
  foreach ( $srcObj in (get-childitem $source )) 
  { 
    $srcObjPath = "$($srcObj.fullname)"
    $destObjPath = "$($destination)\$($srcObj.name)" 
    If((Test-Path -LiteralPath $destination)) 
     {
       copy-item $srcObjPath $destination -recurse
       if ( (Test-Path -Path $destObjPath ) -eq $true)
       {
        if ( (compare-object (gci $srcObjPath -recurse) (gci $destObjPath -recurse)) -eq $null)
        {
         write-output "Compare is good. Remove $($srcObjPath)"
         remove-item $srcObjPath -recurse
        }
        else
        {
          write-output "Compare is bad. Remove $($destObjPath)"
          remove-item $destObjPath -recurse
         }
       }
       else 
       { 
        write-output "$($destination) path is bad" 
       }
     }
  else
  {
    write-output "bad destinaton: $($destination)"
  }
 }
}
```

[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138849/how-do-you-move-files-folders-across-volumes-with-powershell/7404879#7404879)

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of new here, but... Copying things with Robocopy uses a syntax like this:

```
robocopy \\source_host\source_dir \\dest_host\dest_dir *
```

where, * (meaning all) or list of files to be copied.

Personally I wasn't able to copy a directory using robocopy this 'direct way' (source / dest). Only using the `/MIR` parameter.

Comment: I just tested `/MIR`, sadly it still removed the folder and just moved the files within the folder

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is map the network location do a 'Drive' in the same script, and then disconnect from it at the end. I would also simply use the `MOVE` command

e.g.

```
NET USE S: \\networkLocation\c$\newDir
MOVE "C:\user\desktop\working dir\test1" S:
NET USE S: /DELETE
```